# What tax-free retirement accounts are available for self-employed individuals?

Tags: united-states, retirement, ira, self-employment

I'm self employed, so I've started to look at what my options are for saving (tax-free) for retirement. Of course I can do an IRA or Roth IRA, but those have lower caps than a 401k.

I had thought Simple-IRA was a 401k clone for the self-employed, but looking at the details now, it seems it's for small business employees instead.

What other options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a [self-employed 401k](https://www.fidelity.com/retirement/small-business/self-employed-401k), here's an example. You can deposit up to 50K (including the personal cap and the profit sharing/matching portion).

Comment: Heh, I had thought 401k was strictly for companies, so I hadn't even looked at those. thanks!